# Rails Custom Deprecation Notices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, deprecated

Is there a way to create custom deprecation notices for methods and/or associations in my application that I plan on removing and want to log their usage? I have a relationship in one of my models that I don't want to use moving forward and plan to refactor the code at a later time. I would like to create a notice in my development log every time that method is called.

I have seen deprecation notices in Ruby/Rails when using certain methods, and figure there has to be an easy way to do this.

Something like...

```
irb(main):001:0> 1.id
(irb):1: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
=> 3
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Rails 3 you can use the : ["deprecate" method from ActiveSupport](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/deprecate):

```
class Example
  def foo
  end

  deprecate :foo
end
```

It will create an alias for your method and output a warning with a stack trace. You can also use parts of this functionality directly, e.g:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn("Message")
```

It will output the stack trace along with the message.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe:

```
def old_relationship
  warn "[DEPRECATION] old_relationship is deprecated."
  @old_relationship
end

def old_relationship=(object)
  warn "[DEPRECATION] old_relationship is deprecated."
  @old_relationship = object
end
```

Something along those lines for a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

In the majority of cases, you can just raise a warning and call the new method.

```
class Example
  # <b>DEPRECATED:</b> Please use <tt>good_method</tt> instead.
  def bad_method
    warn "`bad_method` is deprecated. Use `good_method` instead."
    good_method
  end

  def good_method
    # ...
  end
end
```

There are libraries or metaprogramming if you need or want to get fancier, but in general that's not a good route to go for something this simple. You should have a pretty good reason to introduce a dependency for something this simple.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my 2 cents:

If you're using [Yard](http://yardoc.org/) instead of [rdoc](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/), your doc comment should look like this:

```
# @deprecated Please use {#useful} instead
```

Lastly, if you adhere to [tomdoc](http://tomdoc.org/), make your comment look like this:

```
# Deprecated: Please use `useful` instead
```

> *Deprecated: Indicates that the method is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. You SHOULD use this to document methods that were Public but will be removed at the next major version.*